# Using cuDF to split a Series of strings into chunks

Tags: python, cudf

I have a cuDF Series containing long strings and I would like to split each string into equal sized chunks.

My code to do this looks something like:

```
import cudf                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                             
s = cudf.Series(["abcdefg", "hijklmnop"])                                                              
                                                                                                       
def chunker(string):                                                                                   
    chunk_size = 3                                                                                     
    return [string[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(string), chunk_size)]                         
                                                                                                       
print(s.apply(chunker))
```

This gives the error:

```
No implementation of function Function(<class 'range'>) found for signature:
 
 >>> range(Literal[int](0), Masked(int32), Literal[int](3))
```

If I replace `len(string)` with a constant, then I get another error complaining about the indexing:

```
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> getitem(Masked(string_view), slice<a:b>)
```

The code works fine in regular Pandas but I was hoping to run this on some really large datasets and benefit from cdDF GPU operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.findall` for this operation with a regular expression to match any character between 1 and 3 (chunk size) times, which will be faster in pandas and cuDF:

```py
import pandas as pd
import cudf

N = 1000000
s = pd.Series(["abcdefg", "hijklmnop"]*N)
gs = cudf.from_pandas(s)

%time out = s.str.findall(".{1,3}")
%time out = gs.str.findall(".{1,3}")
out.head()
CPU times: user 3.55 s, sys: 164 ms, total: 3.72 s
Wall time: 3.7 s
CPU times: user 118 ms, sys: 31.8 ms, total: 150 ms
Wall time: 150 ms

0      [abc, def, g]
1    [hij, klm, nop]
2      [abc, def, g]
3    [hij, klm, nop]
4      [abc, def, g]
dtype: list
```

You may also be interested in [cudf.pandas](https://rapids.ai/cudf-pandas), the zero-code change accelerator for pandas code.